# Should I create a database by project or group them in one

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating few little projects (more or less 10 tables by project), should I create a database for each projects? or group them in one database?

Comment: It depends on your intentions to use these projects separately in the future.
If they will work as a whole - create one database and several schemes.

Comment: I will go for separate databases, since my projects won't share their data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not care.  You can always do `... FROM dbname.tblname ...` if you need to reach across db boundaries.

For your own sanity, make it one project per database, especially if they share nothing.

Comment: I will make a database per project since they don't share anything, thank you!